# Seeking tool to calculate "one second of longitude equals how many meters" based on anywhere in world?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system

[image]I have 4 text boxes that are data driven based on "1 Sec Long Meters S". The problem is this field is not filled out. I'm wondering if there is a tool that will calculate how many meters one second of longitude is based on my location. I will also need to do this for latitude.

Comment: Calculating it for one place is only good for that one place (dependent on latitude), and the ***direction*** of the line will alter the value.  Since the value is without merit, I doubt such a tool has been *or should be* created.

Comment: What about an AOI. Such as a TLM sheet. If the TLM_Sheet_Index (polygon AOI's) have values for these then they must be derived from something.

Comment: TLMs are UTM map sheets.

Comment: For the ellipsoidal equations, see page 25 of [Map Projections: A Working Manual](https://pubs.usgs.gov/pp/1395/report.pdf) by John P. Snyder, USGS PP 1395. It's 22mb so it'll take a few seconds to display.

Comment: So a simple answer is no, there is no tool for this. My thinking was, instead of taking only two points (which is the obvious answer) along the western side of the Sheet AOI, it would take all of the points along that edge from one corner to the other, get the length for each point and then get an average across that side of the sheet.

Answer (score 1):

`(6371000÷(360×60×60))×cos(latitude)`

- `6371000`… earth radius
- `(360x60x60)` … seconds for a full 360°
- `latitude` … your point’s latitude

Comment: You should note that this is a spherical solution, not a spheroidal one.